# Java JDBC, работа с PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

Здраствуйте! Не срабатывает метод setString() обьекта preparedStatement. Вот так не работает:

```
prStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ?"); 
prStmt.setString(1, "cases");
rs = prStmt.executeQuery();
```

А вот так работает:

```
prStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cases"); 
rs = prStmt.executeQuery();
```

Хотя в документации написано:

> void setString(int parameterIndex, String x), где х устанавливается взамен знаку "?"

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А для названия таблицы вроде так делать нельзя, только для полей

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Для названия таблицы **нельзя** использовать параметризацию ?
>
> ответ от [@Алексей-Шиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

вместо этого можно использовать переменную при **создании** запроса

```
String tableName = "cases";

String query = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;

prStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); 
rs = prStmt.execute();
```

алтерьантива для запроса

```
String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM $1%s WHERE .... ? ",  tableName);
```

---

также исправьте команду

из документации [docs.oracle.com - Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#execute_ps)

С `Statement objects`, для запуска `PreparedStatement object`, можно:

- запустить `executeQuery` если результат имеет ОДНО значение `ResultSet`
- запустить `executeUpdate` если запрос НЕ ИМЕЕТ результат значений
- запустить `execute` если результат имеет МНОГО значений

Comment: Хотите сказать, что можно применить `?` к имени таблицы?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет конечно. Название таблицы нельзя использовать как ? Вы тут правы.

Comment: Но мне кажется, вопрос состоит  именно в этом... да там не `execute`...Но ошибка не в этом у автора и он как раз об этом и спрашивает.. Думаю стоит это объяснить в ответе.

Comment: Теперь все ясно, благодарю за помощь